# Why its wrong in java:

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-expression

Hello friends i have a question to define id in java.
why this define is wrong:

```
if(0<=hours<24)
```

but

```
if(0<=hours&&hours<24)
```

is true.

Comment: Every language has its own syntax.

Comment: Because that's the way the language works.

Answer (score 5):

The first one parses as

```
if((0<=hours)<24)
```

or (for example, if `hours` was `>= 0`)

```
if(true<24)
```

which is invalid as a boolean cannot be less than an int.

In fact, no languages than I recall, except Python, allow this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first inequality evaluates to a boolean. So this becomes,

```
if (true <= 24)
```

In Java, comparison between boolean and integers are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the type of `0<=hours` is a `boolean` and the `<` operator does not work on `boolean` and `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is syntactically incorrect. If you want to compare a variable against two other expressions you should have a valid operator like and (&&). That's why the second one is correct.

```
if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
```

Here you are saying if `hours` is greater than or equal to 0 and at the same time stricktly less than 24.